# How to find count of Child using parentId

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, hierarchy

[image]

How to find the count of children in each row?

For example:

```
   1 ROW COUNT=1
   2 ROW COUNT=0 
   ...
```

and so on. In the next column

Comment: An rCTE (Recursive Common Table Expression), would seem the best way to go. Have you made any attempts so far to solve this problem yourself? If not, there are plenty of resources out there on how to use a rCTE to navigate hierarchical data in SQL Server.

Comment: Since this seems to be a table of children, there can't be a parent with 0 children when just querying this table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using recursive CTE, but it should be done with simple join. First, find the count of each node, excluding node without parents:

```
SELECT [ParentID] 
      ,COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable 
WHERE [ParentID] <> 0
GROUP BY [ParentID];
```

If this is OK, just join to the initial table:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable T1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT [ParentID] 
          ,COUNT(*) AS [all_childs]
    FROM MyTable 
    WHERE [ParentID] <> 0
    GROUP BY [ParentID]
) T2
    oN T1.[parentID] = T2.[ParentID];
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be okay, you need `isnull()` function when `ROW COUNT=0`

```
 SELECT 
        PA.ID, 
        PA.Title_Name, 
        ISNULL(P.COUNTT,0) CountOfID 
 FROM #My_Table PA
 LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT COUNT(*) COUNTT, Parent_ID from #My_Table GROUP BY Parent_ID
             ) as P on P.Parent_ID = PA.ID
```